# Can rsync preserve directories information?

Tags: rsync

I would like to rsync only certain files within a directory, but I would like to preserve the directory format.  I am using this with crontab to back up certain files only.
For example:

```
home/dir1/file1
home/dir1/file2
home/dir2/file1
```

The command I am using is

```
rsync -av /home/dir*/file* backup/
```

However, it only sends all the files to the same backup directory.  Is there a way to specify to split these?  Sorry if this is super basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want the `-R` option, as in `rsync -avR /home/dir*/file* backup/`

Then instead of [I presume] everything ending up "flat" under `backup`, you should get:

```
backup
    home
        dir1
            file1
            file2
            ...
        dir2
            file3
            file4
            ...
        dir...
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. This got me there.  I ended up with a long trail of directories, but after looking up the -R flag, I was able to use a '/.' in my directory path to break it.

Comment: You're welcome.  `rsync` is a truly great program--with _lots_ of options.  Sometimes you just have to start simply and gradually build up options until you get what you want.  I recently answered another similar rsync question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/741346/rsync-directory-so-all-changes-appear-atomically/741420#741420